# firebase database update field based on another field value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two fields in the database, I want to copy the old value from `fieldB`to another field `fieldA` before updating the `fieldB`:

```
MyDatabase.ref('/myusers/' + firebaseUser.uid).update({ 
   fieldA: firebaseUser.uid.fieldB,
   fieldB: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
 });
```

I get an error saying that the property is undefined for **firebaseUser.uid.fieldB**.

How can I achieve this the correct way?

### update

Here is how it looks like after your hints:

```
MyDatabase.ref('/myusers/' + firebaseUser.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    var usrname = snapshot.val().username;
    toastr.info('Success.', 'Welcome ' + usrname + '!');
    $scope.oldfieldB = snapshot.val().fieldB;
});

MyDatabase.ref('/myusers/' + firebaseUser.uid).update({
   fieldA: $scope.oldfieldB,
   fieldB: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```

I get the same error: undefined `firebaseUser.uid.fieldA`.

Comment: How do you initialize your `firebaseUser` object ?

Comment: And what is `firebaseUser.uid`? It's used like a `string` to build the ref's path, but is expected to have a `fieldB` property?

Comment: @cartant It has a fieldB and fieldA. it is the user's ID in the users tree.

Comment: @cartant i updated my question and now you can have a global look at the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the `value` event before performing the `update`:

```
var ref = MyDatabase.ref('/myusers/' + firebaseUser.uid);
ref.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
  return ref.update({
    fieldA: snapshot.val().fieldB,
    fieldB: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can perform the read and write in a single call if you use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction):

```
var ref = MyDatabase.ref('/myusers/' + firebaseUser.uid);
ref.transaction(function (data) {
  if (data !== null) {
    data.fieldA = data.fieldB;
    data.fieldB = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  }
  return data;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a string, right?

```
 firebaseUser.uid
```

The error caused by `firebaseUser.uid` does not have `fieldB` property (as it's only a string)

You should save the value of `fieldB` to a variable and update the database with it

```
MyDatabase.ref('/myusers/' + firebaseUser.uid).update({ 
   fieldA: fieldBVariable,
   fieldB: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
 });
```

Comment: thanks, i updated my question according to your answer, but i still can't get it working. could you update your answer?